# Why Is This "OnScroll" JavaScript Function Not Being Called?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript code that, when the page is being scrolled DOWN, the navigation bar should hide (or `margin-top: -100px`). But, when the page is being scrolled up, the navigation bar should appear (or `margin-top: 0`).

I don't understand why this function is not being called when the page is scrolled. Is there something wrong in my code? Please look below:

```
let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
  let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "-100px";
  }

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

The main reason that I know that the function isn't being called, is that when I added some simple script to the function (such as `alert("Hello World!")`, that did not happen either.

Thank you, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the scroll happens at the window level? Maybe what is scrolling is an inner element, like a div.

Comment: Any errors in your dev tools console? (Since the code works, are you sure it's `navbar` and not `nav-bar` or some other silly misspelling?  Or perhaps the classic mistake of putting a hash-symbol in your id (`id="#navbar"` instead of `id="navbar"`). But if your alert doesn't work, then it sounds like you are not including your script correctly.

Comment: @ippi am not sure why this doesn't work, as it should, but the accepted answer works fine. I don't know if it something with MY browser or some other issue. Either way, the accepted works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple `window.onscroll` declarations in your codebase? If so you're overwriting them each time.

```
let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "-100px";
  }

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to accept and upvote yesterday, the SQL servers at StackOverflow were being updated.